# AWS Ruby2 SDK, what's the difference between Resource and Client

Tags: aws-sdk

I'm using the `aws-sdk` gem and I don't understand the difference between a `Client` and a `Resource`. This blog post isn't super helpful:

> Each service module has a Client class that provides a 1-to-1 mapping
>   of the service API. Each service module now also has a Resource class
>   that provides an object-oriented interface to work with.

[link](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1H87IVGVUMIB5/Using-Resources)

The documentation on the two classes isn't much help either:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Resource.html

So what am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this and found :

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/java-sdk-resource-apis-preview/

"Instead of exposing all of the methods of the **service** as part of a single class, the resource-style API includes multiple classes, each of which represents a particular type of **resource** for the service.... Code written to the new (*resource-style*) API will generally be shorter, cleaner, and easier to comprehend"